# Regex for no space between attributes html

Tags: html, regex

How to detected no space between attributes.
Example:

```
 <div style="margin:37px;"/></div>
 <span title=''style="margin:37px;" /></span>
 <span title="" style="margin:37px;" /></span>
 <a title="u" hghghgh  title="j" >

 <a title=""gg  ff>
```

correct: `1,3,4`
incorrect: `2,5`
How to detected incorrect?

I've tried with this:

`<(.*?=(['"]).*?\2)([\S].*)|(^/)>`

But it's not working.

Comment: Don't forget http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/284111

Answer (score 3):

[You should not use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454), unless for learning purpose.

---

#### http://regexr.com/3cge1

```
<\w+(\s+[\w-]+(=(['"]?)[^"']*\3)?)*\s*/?>
```

---

This regular expression matches even if you don't have any attribute at all. It works for self-closing tags, and if the attribute has no value.

---

- `<\w+` Match opening `<` and `\w` characters.
- `(\s+[\w-]+(=(['"])[^"']*\3)?)*` zero or more attributes that must start with a white space. It contains two parts:

  - `\s+[\w-]+` attribute name after mandatory space
  - `(=(['"])[^"']*\3)?` optional attribute value
- `\s*/?>` optional white space and optional `/` followed by closing `>`.

---

Here is a test for the strings:

```
var re = /<\w+(\s+[\w-]+(=(['"]?)[^"']*\3)?)*\s*\/?>/g;

! '<div style="margin:37px;"/></div>'.match(re);
false

! '<span title=\'\'style="margin:37px;" /></span>'.match(re);
true

! '<span title="" style="margin:37px;" /></span>'.match(re);
false

! '<a title="u" hghghgh  title="j" >'.match(re);
false

! '<a title=""gg  ff>'.match(re);
true
```

---

### Display all incorrect tags:

```
var html = '<div style="margin:37px;"></div> <span title=\'\'style="margin:37px;"/><a title=""gg ff/> <span title="" style="margin:37px;" /></span> <a title="u" hghghgh title="j"example> <a title=""gg ff>';
var tagRegex = /<\w+[^>]*\/?>/g;
var validRegex = /<\w+(\s+[\w-]+(=(['"]?)[^"']*\3)?)*\s*\/?>/g;

html.match(tagRegex).forEach(function(m) {
  if(!m.match(validRegex)) {
    console.log('Incorrect', m);
  }
});
```

Will output

```
Incorrect <span title=''style="margin:37px;"/>
Incorrect <a title=""gg ff/>
Incorrect <a title="u" hghghgh title="j"example>
Incorrect <a title=""gg ff>
```

---

### Update for the comments

```
<\w+(\s+[\w-]+(="[^"]*"|='[^']*'|=[\w-]+)?)*\s*/?>
```

Comment: it is working but i want opposite result(pick incorrect)

Comment: You could pick the incorrect ones using `if(!string.match(re)) { ... }`

Comment: I edited the tests to return `true` for the incorrect ones.

Comment: Something is wrong. Try for this example:<div style="margin:37px;"></div>
 <span title=''style="margin:37px;"/><a title=""gg  ff/>
 <span title="" style="margin:37px;" /></span>
 <a title="u" hghghgh title="j"example>
 <a title=""gg  ff>

Comment: So, what are you trying to do eventually with the incorrect matches? Are you trying to fix them (e.g. add a space where needed)?

Comment: I want to edit my answer to do that, shall I do it in Javascript?

Comment: I edited my answer for that. Basically we are iterating all tags and validating them using the main regex.

Comment: Thanks work. This is impossible in one regex or hard?

Comment: It is not impossible, but it will be unnecessarily complex and ugly. There is no real benefit in using one regex instead of two.

Comment: I added an update at the end of my answer for your new test string. Please note that there are other cases where it might fail, e.g., a script containing Javascript that includes html in strings.

Comment: Yes i have problems with js in html, but I try to fix them (another regex) but I have new examples when not work, if u can look: http://paste.ofcode.org/LXikKQG3un68tnpwRbBMKJ

Comment: How about using a .NET library like suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/100393/721215? Doing it by regex is good for learning and for simple inputs (like the ones in your question), but it gets complicated quickly for more general input.

Comment: Do you want this `<div class=gnt>` to be printed as incorrect?

Comment: `<\w+(\s+[\w-]+(="[^"]*"|='[^']*'|=[\w-]+)?)*\s*/?>`

Comment: Did you test the last regex?

Comment: Yes it work but not for all, 
exception:  <a  onclick=gbar.qs(this);gbar.logger.il(1,{t:8}); title="" >  It should be correct

Comment: `<\w+(\s+[\w-]+(="[^"]*"|='[^']*'|=[^\s'"]+)?)*\s*/?>`

Comment: Hello, I found new exception, It should be correct.  <input id="main-search-text" type="text" class="autofocus" x-webkit-speech autocomplete="off" value="" required="required" name="string" placeholder="dfdfdfdf? /> ==> (placeholder="dfdfdfdf?) missing quotation marks but that is correct

Comment: BTW, `placeholder="dfdfdfdf?` is missing the closing double-quote, it is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex , i think it will work

```
<\w*[^=]*=["'][\w;:]*["'][\s/]+[^>]*>
```

`<` - starting bracket

`\w*` - one or more alphanumeric character

`[^=]*=` - It will cover all the character till '=' shows up
`["'][\w;:]*["']` - this will match two cases 
        1. one with single quote with having strings optional
        2. one with double quote with having strings optional

`[\s/]+` - match the space or '\' atleast one occurence

`[^>]*` - this will match all the character till '>' closing bracket

Comment: Please add an explanation of your answer. Code only answers are rarely useful to someone trying to learn.

Comment: Not working, but i change a little and works:[code]<[a-z]+\s[a-z]+=[\'\"][\w;:]*[\"\'][\w]+[^>]*(>)

Comment: i found next example <a title="u" hghghgh title="j"example>  did not work

Comment: @wroe12 yeah you have to actually , i think  flags are not enabled in your case :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this pattern to work, finding incorrect lines 2 and 5 as you requested:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = r'<[a-z]+\s[a-z]+=[\'\"][\w;:]*[\"\'][\w]+.*'

>>> html = """
 <div style="margin:37px;"/></div>
 <span title=''style="margin:37px;" /></span>
 <span title="" style="margin:37px;" /></span>
 <a title="u" hghghgh  title="j" >

 <a title=""gg  ff>
"""

>>> bad = re.findall(p, html)
>>> print '\n'.join(bad)
<span title=''style="margin:37px;" /></span>
<a title=""gg  ff>
```

**regex broken down:**

```
p = r'<[a-z]+\s[a-z]+=[\'\"][\w;:]*[\"\'][\w]+.*'
```

`<` - starting bracket

`[a-z]+\s` - 1 or more lowercase letters followed by a space

`[a-z]+=` - 1 or more lowercase letters followed by an equals sign

`[\'\"]` - match a single or double quote one time

`[\w;:]*` - match an alphnumeric character (a-zA-Z0-9_) or a colon or semi-colon 0 or more times

`[\"\']` - again match a single or double quote one time

`[\w]+` - match an alphanumeric character one or more times(this catches the lack of a space you wanted to detect) ***

`.*` - match anything 0 or more times(gets rest of the line)

Comment: for this examples works but fail with this:<span title=''style="margin:37px;"><a title=""gg  ff>

Comment: ah.. didn't see this in time

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about this I am not so experienced at regex but this looks like it is working well

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/n3xrchwk/2/)

```
<([a-z]+)(\s+[a-z\-]+(="[^"]*")?)*\s*\/?>([^<]+(<\/$1>))?
```

Currently `<([a-z]+)` will mostly work but with web component and `<ng-*` this would better be `\w+`

### ---------------

Output:

> ```
> <div style="margin:37px;">div</div> correct
>
> <span title=" style="margin:37px;" />span1</span> incorrect
>
> <span title="" style="margin:37px;" />span2</span> correct
>
> <a title="u" title="j">link</a> correct
>
> <a title=""href="" alt="" required>test</a> incorrect
>
> <img src="" data-abc="" required> correct
>
> <input type=""style="" /> incorrect
> ```